# Java object its not saving its atribute values

Tags: java, dictionary, object

Good afternoon.

I have a class City that receives different distance values to other City objects.

However, after I create the City's and add the distances, every City gets the same distance values, which are the values from the last City added.

That said, after running, the output of cityA.toString should be {B=5, C=4, D=7, E=6, F=5, G=7, H=4, I=2, J=9} and not {A=6, B=5, C=5, D=6, E=4, F=8, G=5, H=4, I=3, J=8}

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
public class City {

private String name;
private static HashMap<String, Integer> distancias;

public City(String name){
    this.name = name;
    distancias = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

public void insertDistances(City city, int dist) {
    distancias.put(city.getName(), dist);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    City cityA = new City("A");
    City cityB = new City("B");
    City cityC = new City("C");
    City cityD = new City("D");
    City cityE = new City("E");
    City cityF = new City("F");
    City cityG = new City("G");
    City cityH = new City("H");
    City cityI = new City("I");
    City cityJ = new City("J");

    cityA.insertDistances(cityB, 5);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityC, 4);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityD, 7);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityE, 6);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityF, 5);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityG, 7);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityH, 4);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityI, 2);
    cityA.insertDistances(cityJ, 9);

    cityB.insertDistances(cityA, 6);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityC, 5);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityD, 6);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityE, 4);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityF, 8);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityG, 5);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityH, 4);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityI, 3);
    cityB.insertDistances(cityJ, 8);

}

}
```

Comment: remove the `static` modifier from `distancias`

Comment: Where's your `toString` method?

Comment: Yes coz  `private static HashMap<String, Integer> distancias;` is static

Answer (score 0):

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> distancias;
```

remove static 
use `private  HashMap<String, Integer> distancias` instead`

A static variable is common to all the instances (or objects) of the class because it is a class level variable.